# Firebase multi-tenancy with multiple users

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm looking at Firebase as a backend for an MVP multi-tenant app. The app will be fully white labelled for each tenant, with each tenant signing up it's own user base. There will definitely be crossovers where users can register for more than one tenant however and I can't seem to see if this is supported by Firebase? essentially I would need to allow a user to register using the same email address to any number of tenants, without necessarily being aware that the tenants are the same system.

Is there anything that supports this?

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Multi-tenancy is now supported by Google Cloud Identity Platform. Based on your question, this seems to be what you are looking for. See docs: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-quickstart

Answer (score -1):

You can create a dedicated Firebase project for each of your tenant. User accounts in one Firebase Authentication project are completely segregated from other projects.

Comment: This makes it really difficult if you have many tenants and there will be a limit on number of projects created in Firebase. Can you please suggest any other solution?

Comment: Been thinking about this issue myself, would it make sense to attached some kind of tenant id to username e.g. if user kimopop@example.com registers in firebase they will be stored with a suffix app_domain.kimopop@example.com  am not sure how this will work for federated accounts though.